# Does Flatbuffer use integer bit packing encoding like protobuf?

Tags: flatbuffers

Does flatbuffers employ any special encoding for integers or other types, like Protobufs does for integers with zigzag + packing? This can be a huge space savings. I can't find any reference in the documentation one way or another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't, since FlatBuffers is optimized for direct access, much like structs/arrays in programming languages. Protobuf varints can take up to 10x longer to decode than just reading a scalar from memory, and depending on the use case, also make it harder to access randomly (such as inside an array).

That said, it be a nice optional feature to have, and was already hinted at here: https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/issues/5875. You could open an issue/PR about it if you find it really important.